# How to first time set up Ubuntu 10.04 internet connection?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, connection

Here is information that I think may be useful to diagnose what's wrong with my settings.

I have a WiFi router, to which a Mac (M1), a Mac (M2), and a Windows PC (W) are connected via wireless, and a Ubuntu server (U) is connected via ethernet cable. All M1, M2, W, and U all have ip like

```
192.168.1.xxx
192.168.1.125 # for U
```

M1/M2 can download/upload files to internet, such as wget, brew commands run well.
I can also ssh from M1/M2 to U, from U to M1/M2. In another word, I think network of U works fine internally.

U is a server I just got. The problem now I think it is that U is not connected to outside, i.e., internet. When I try to wget something, like below

```
wget https://github.com/valid/path/file.name.txt
```

This runs well on M1 and M2 and I can get file.name.txt, while if I run it on U, I would get:

```
Resolving github.com... 192.30.255.112, 192.30.255.113
Connecting to github.com|192.30.255.112|:443... connected.
OpenSSL: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

Some info about U:

```
uname -a
Linux HK2DR22 2.6.32-21-server #32-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 16 09:17:34 UTC 2010 x86_4 GNU/Linux

lsb_release -a
NO LSB modules are available
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS
Release: 10.04
```

No GUI for U, only command line.
Yes, I know it's old version Ubuntu. However for some reason I have to stick to this version at the moment.

I have /etc/network/interfaces like this

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.125
gateway 192.168.1.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
dns-nameservers 208.67.222.222

auto eth1
# blah blah, but since eth1 to eth5 are not connected
auto eth2
auto eth3
auto eth4
auto eth5
```

Here is some other commands/outputs

```
sudo service networking restart
restart: Unknown instance:
service networking status
networking stop/waiting
service network-manager status
network-manager: unrecognized service
ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.14.110) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lax31s01-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.14.110): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 
time=11.6 ms
```

How can I get connection to internet? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IP for `github.com` resolves fine:

> ```
> Resolving github.com... 192.30.255.112, 192.30.255.113
> ```

But the SSL connection fails:

> ```
> OpenSSL: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
> Unable to establish SSL connection.
> ```

Aditionally, your `ping` to Google works fine:

> ```
> 64 bytes from lax31s01-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.14.110): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=11.6 ms
> ```

---

It looks like GitHub is trying to upgrade the connection to a protocol that your ancient version of `wget` (or even `libssl` / `libcrypto`) doesn't support. Additionally, your certificates are going to be *waaaaaay* out of date.

---

If this is a new install (as the title implies), then I would ***strongly*** recommend just using a more recent release of Ubuntu - [18.04](https://www.ubuntu.com/download) for example... Do a fresh install.

10.04.4 was released in 2012, and the desktop release went end-of-life in 2013 [[ref]](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases). The packages for `lucid` were also removed in 2015 [[ref]](https://packages.ubuntu.com/)

---

I've just confirmed that this doesn't work on a completely fresh installation of Ubuntu Server 10.04.4:

```
attie@ubuntu:~/x$ wget --version
GNU Wget 1.12 built on linux-gnu.
[...]

attie@ubuntu:~$ wget https://github.com/attie/libxbee3/blob/master/conn.c
--2018-05-26 19:38:55--  https://github.com/attie/libxbee3/blob/master/conn.c
Resolving github.com... 192.30.253.112, 192.30.253.113
Connecting to github.com|192.30.253.112|:443... connected.
OpenSSL: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

---

To address your comment, `wget` is "*fine*" - it works, and you'll probably have internet access... try this for eaxmple:

```
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/wget-1.19.3.tar.gz
```

The issue you have is that your versions of `wget`/`libssl`/`libcrypto` are stuck in the past, and with the advances in security, you'll find that much of the internet will become inaccessible for you.

You will be able to access HTTP, and some HTTPS servers (but not all).

As the packages for `lucid` are gone, I tried building a more recent version of wget, but alas, I have no compiler:

```
attie@ubuntu:~/x/wget-1.19.3$ ./configure
configure: configuring for GNU Wget 1.19.3
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/home/attie/x/wget-1.19.3':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details
```

If you're lucky, and you have a functional toolchain on hand, then you could try building a more modern `wget`, and `libssl`, and `libcrypto` (the list will go on). It's not going to be a quick job.

```
$ ldd $(which wget)
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffc8e59000)
        libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007fa1475c3000)
        libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007fa1473be000)
        libssl.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007fa147155000)
        libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007fa146d11000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fa146af7000)
        libidn.so.11 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11 (0x00007fa1468c4000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa1464fa000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fa1462dd000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa147aad000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fa1460d9000)
```

If I were you... I'd push to install a more recent (and supported) release.

Comment: As I stated, for some reason I was not allowed to upgrade to 18.04 for this server. I have to follow this. And it's not github problem, the wget command was just an example to show wget does not work on the Ubuntu server, but on my Mac. I could wget any from the Ubuntu server, while I could from my Mac.

Comment: Plus, I have to solve the downloading problem if I want to update to current Ubuntu version. Now I cannot download (probably no uploading either)

Comment: I've updated my answer. You will not be able to update from 10.04 to anything... no packages means no update and no upgrade... this is a fresh install job.

Comment: I'll follow what you guided to see if it works.... THANKS!

Comment: I'll go ask for permission to upgrade (too much hassle to keep the low version). thanks